# Task - Endangered species. How to solve this problem? Why I can't read property 'length' of undefined. The description of the question is below

Tags: javascript

An HTML div element contains lists of endangered species grouped by continent and the species population status.

```
<div>
   <ul data-continent="North America">
      <li data-species="California condor">Critically Endangered</li>
      <li data-species="American bison">Near Threatened</li>
   </ul>
   <ul data-continent="Europe">
      <li data-species="Cave bear">Extinct</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Implement the function endangeredSpecies that returns how endangered a species is on a particular continent.
For example endangeredSpecies('North America', 'American bison') should return 'Near Threatened'.

My attempt:

```js
function endangeredSpecies(continent, species) {
  let div = document.querySelector('div').children;

  let status = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    console.log(div[i]);
    if (div[i].dataset.continent === continent) {
      status = getStatus(div[i].children, species);
    }
  }
  console.log(status);
}


endangeredSpecies('North America')
```

```html
<div>
  <ul data-continent="North America">
    <li data-species="California condor">Critically Endangered</li>
    <li data-species="American bison">Near Threatened</li>
  </ul>
  <ul data-continent="Europe">
    <li data-species="Cave bear">Extinct</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant code. We are missing `getStatus`

Comment: @mplungjan I'v already added the 'getStatus' function, I had missed to write it on my code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler than you thought

```js
const endangeredSpecies = (continent, species) => document
  .querySelector(`div [data-continent="${continent}"]`)
  .querySelector(`[data-species="${species}"]`).textContent;



console.log(
  endangeredSpecies('North America', 'American bison')
)
console.log(
  endangeredSpecies('Europe', 'Cave bear')
)
```

```html
<div>
  <ul data-continent="North America">
    <li data-species="California condor">Critically Endangered</li>
    <li data-species="American bison">Near Threatened</li>
  </ul>
  <ul data-continent="Europe">
    <li data-species="Cave bear">Extinct</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to query all species in a continent you can do this:

```js
const endangeredSpecies = continent => [...document.querySelectorAll(`div [data-continent="${continent}"] li`)].map(li =>
  `${li.dataset.species}: ${li.textContent}`).join('\n');

console.log(
  endangeredSpecies('North America')
)
console.log(
  endangeredSpecies('Europe')
)
```

```html
<div>
  <ul data-continent="North America">
    <li data-species="California condor">Critically Endangered</li>
    <li data-species="American bison">Near Threatened</li>
  </ul>
  <ul data-continent="Europe">
    <li data-species="Cave bear">Extinct</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function endangeredSpecies(continent, species) {
 
let tags=document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for(let i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
    if(tags[i].getAttribute('data-species')==species){
      let parent=tags[i].parentElement;
      if(parent.getAttribute('data-continent')==continent)
        return tags[i].innerHTML;
 
    }
    
  }
}
```